# Retreiving facebook comments by API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I would like to maintain a copy of all Facebook comments on my business page for analysis purposes.
I created an app and tokens and managed to query all posts on the page by this call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{page-id}/feed?access_token={token}
```

And for every post I can get the full comments by this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{object-id}/comments?summary=1&filter=stream&order=reverse_chronological&access_token={token}
```

That worked great but I have two problems:

1. I would like to retrieve all new comments on all posts. My page has 500+ posts. It would be very wasteful to query each of the 500 pages on daily basis to get all comments because 490+ of them will probably have no new comments on an any given day.
2. The results from the comment API call is very basis and does not provide the user name like the below sample

   {
   "data": [
   {
   "created_time": "2021-06-10T23:52:09+0000",
   "message": "test 3",
   "id": "xxxx_xxxx"
   },

Is there a way to retrieve all comments regardless of the page and provide more info in the result? There are commercial tools that perform similar functionality like Sudota so theoritcally it should be possible but I could not find that in the API documentation.

Comment: Implement webhooks, and subscribe for updates to the `feed` of your page - then Facebook will notify _you_, when stuff changes, instead of you having to poll all the time. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Comment: Getting `from` info for comments _should_ work according to documentation, when you use a page access token. But there’s lots of questions on here by other people, who also could not get that to work properly. My guess is that the minimum requirement would be that the app is in live mode, but it is unclear whether there are others. (And dev/live mode only applies to apps owned by individuals any more, for business-owned apps you would have to looks into the different _access levels_ and figure out which one allows access to what exactly.)

Comment: @CBroe Hi, how do I set my app in live mode via that new access levels? Is an advanced access like a live mode for that subject?

Comment: Business apps do not have app modes and rely exclusively on access levels. For all other types, it should be live mode still.